# Dockerized nodes of elasticsearch cluster in EC2, production environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, docker

What are advantages and disadvantages of using Elastic Search nodes in docker containers in EC2?

My management forces me to do so, but I don't see any benefits doing it in EC2, where one Elastic Search node is one EC2 instance. I would like to use configuration management tool only (Ansible, for example).

Thanks!